how to use use custom Y Axis Axis Format in Aapache superset
I am using Apache superset. I need to use custom Y Axis Axis Format number format. I have data like sample data:

I want to show data like 23,860 crore instead of  23860,86,00,000. I have tried below like

But it show above like.
How to show my own custom top of 23,860 crore instead of 200G? Is it possible?

Try $,.2f to format as currency with two decimal places and comma separators.
